# REPLACE() - Replace seat Status and actualyze matriz bus_seat with new seat's status

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I Want a code that i can choose a seat to sell, and if it is
Available, it need be actualized to Unavailable in matrix bus_seat.

```
bus_seat = ["1 - avaliable", "2 - avaliable", "3 - unvaliable", "4 - avaliable"]
for seat in bus_seat:
  if seat == str(input("Choose a seat to sell.")):
    seat.replace("avaliable", "unvaliable")
    print(seat.bus_seat)
  else:
    print(seat.bus_seat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
bus_seat = [{"seat no.": 1, "status": "available"}, {"seat no.": 2, "status": "unavailable"}]
seat = input("Seat to sell: ")
for s in bus_seat:
     if int(s["seat no."]) == int(seat):
         if s["status"] == "available":
             s["status"] = "unavailable"
         else:
             s["status"] = "available"
```

Comment: Okay, well available and unavailable only flip back and forth, so If you select a seat that is unavailable, it will turn it to available. You'd have to add more logic to the code to prevent it from doing that.

Comment: @wender.mezini if this is the correct answer, could you mark it as so?